# Couple problems and classic wolf/goat/cabbage and abstraction

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, puzzle

I was reviewing Dijkstra's approach on the problem/puzzle of how 2 married couple can cross a river with 1 boat that can carry 2 people. The original problem's restriction is that the wife can't be in the presence of another husband without hers being present as well.
His approach was to change the original restriction to be that the husbands have to stay together and the result of this abstraction is that there is no longer a need to distinguish between husband/wife so that the problem is simplified.
Although what he says is clear, I don't understand why the restriction is required in the first place.
The problem seems identical to the goat/cabbage/wolf where the cabbage and wolf had a symmetry with the goat (neither could be left alone with the goat) and hence replaced with an abstract concept "a".

Isn't this also applicable in the case of the couples? Is the approach of having an extra restriction redundant or not?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking? However, Dijkstra's remarks aren't very clear either, but note that he does not "change" the restriction: he derives an alternative but equivalent formulation of the original restriction.

Comment: @RobArthan: The alternative formulation is clear. But I don't understand why is it needed. In his abstraction for the goat/cabbage/problem he pointed out the symmetry of wolf/cabbage and abstracted them out as a single entity. This seems directly applicable to the married couples problem. So what I am trying to ask is if I am wrong and that the exact symmetry between cabbage/wolf does not exist in the married couples problem and the only way to simplify it is with that restatement. Is my question clear now?

Comment: After further thought, I see that I should have qualified my comment: Dijkstra *purports* to present an equivalent formulation, but his analysis is just wrong. There is a solution that does separate the two husbands. Dijkstra seems to be so keen to find abstractions that he doesn't actually address the problem as stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course if you can solve the problem with the husbands being apart at some point, that's just fine. That is, there is clearly no a priori *need* for imposing this additional restriction: the problem is stated the way it is ... why would you be *required* to add another restriction? That makes little sense.

Indeed, there is obviously a danger in trying to impose restrictions: maybe in doing so the problem actually becomes more difficult, if not impossible to solve. So, imposing further restrictions is not only unnecessary, but it could even be dangerous.

Now, one possible explanation for Dijkstra making this additional restriction  is the following. Maybe Dijkstra analyzed the puzzle, and came to the conclusion that there is no solution possible if the husbands get separated. And note, depending on the nature of the puzzle, one can come to such a conclusion without actually finding all solutions to the puzzle, or even just a single one. And, if that is so, then yes, you might as well treat the two husbands as one item, thus eliminating the need to distinguish between the two, and treating them ,as you say, as one 'object' '$a$'.

Indeed, if you do treat the two husbands as one object '$a$', with the understanding that $a$ alone fills up the whole boat, it is easy to find a solution to this problem: Have the two wives row across, and have one of them return. Now send over '$a$', and have the second wive return, and finally have the two wives go across together again.

However, as others have pointed out, it turns out that there is *also* a solution with you keep the two husbands together: have one couple row across, after which the husband rows back to fetch the other husband, and then the wife rows back to fetch the other wife.

So, we know that the restriction that Dijkstra imposes is not necessitated at all. In fact, I would say Dijkstra was really rather 'lucky' in creating the additional restriction. How did he know that there was a solution where you could keep the two husbands together?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Aha!  I tried to find a solution with separating husbands and couldn't find one myself ... so figured that this was true ... but then when trying to come up with a proof that it is no use separating the husbands I couldn't find a proof either ... now I know why :P Can't believe I didn't see this solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Bram28: My question though is not why he imposed the restriction. But why is it needed to begin with. In Dijkstra's abstraction for the goat/cabbage/problem he pointed out the symmetry of wolf/cabbage and abstracted them out as a single entity. This seems directly applicable to the married couples problem. Isn't it? If yes then why did he try to achieve the abstraction with that restriction?

Comment: @MishaLavrov: You are correct that the sequence you mention is a solution, but I think it is not symmetric which I think was Dijskstra's original purpose i.e. display a solution that is symmetric. And that is related to my original question (check comment above)

Comment: @Jim I was responding to a statement in the answer, which has been removed now, so my comment is also now redundant.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: No I don't think it is redundant, it helped me understand Dijkstra's purpose since I didn't originally think there is another alternative so thank you for that

Comment: @Jim  Hmm, you are asking three questions here.  First, you ask: why is the restriction needed?  This is what I answered in my Answer, and my answer is: No, the restriction is not needed at all. And, as Misha showed, there is in fact a solution that does break up the husbands.

Comment: Second, you ask: isn't this married couples problem like the wolf/goat/cabbage problem .. in particular in that in both problems you can do some kind of abstraction? That question I did not answer ... and in fact I am a little clear what the abstraction is that they are supposed to have in common. Did Dijkstra make a similar retriction that the wolf and the cabbage should never be separated?  What does he mean by replacing them as a single entity 'a'?  It might be helpful to provide a link or copy some text here.

Comment: Third, you ask why did he try to achieve the abstraction with that restriction? OK, I assume that by 'the abstraction' you mean whatever abstraction you think that both problems have in common? Well, again, I don;t know exactly what abstraction he is trying to achieve, so again hard for me to comment on.  But, if Dijkstra sees an analogy between the two problems, then whatever helped him solve the one problem he figures would help him solve the other one as well. Couldn't that be the reason for him doing this?  But still, is it needed (back to your first question)? Of course not.

Comment: @Bram28: You are right, I see where I was confused now. The husbands can not be abstracted away before that restriction is added. Without that restriction it is not possible to consider them as interchangeable if we distinguish between the couples

Comment: I think if your answer includes that clarification it answers my questions. Thank you!

Comment: @Jim OK, I added something to my Answer that, I think, is to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is a solution that does separate the two husbands. Let's say the couples are Mr. and Mrs. Smith and Mr. and Mrs. Jones:

1. The Smiths row across together.
2. Mr. Smith rows back.
3. Mr. Smith and Mr. Jones row across together.
4. Mrs. Smith rows back.
5. Mrs. Smith and Mrs. Jones row across together.

Dijkstra would very likely have hated it, but the most effective means we have for analysing protocols like this is informed trial and error (a.k.a. [model checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_checking)). Model checking does often benefit from an intelligent choice of abstraction.

Comment: Could this solution be generalized for 3 couples?